# use fermat's little theorem to evaluate $9^{200}$ mod 19

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

use Fermat's little theorem to evaluate $9^{200}$ mod 19

My solution is since 18 = 9- Now $200 = 9 \cdot 11 + 2$

and then I continute until I reached $9^2 = 9$
is it that I have to find $9^2 \mod 19$?

Comment: we have $$9^{200}\equiv 5 \mod 19$$

Answer (score 1):

Because of $gcd(9,19)=1$ and $200\equiv 2\ (\ mod\ 18\ )$, we have

$$9^{200}\equiv 9^2\equiv 5\ (\ mod\ 19\ )$$

Comment: that is all I need to do?

Comment: Yes, this is Euler's theorem : $gcd(a,n)=1\rightarrow a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1\ (\ mod\ n)\ $

Comment: but I need to use FLT ?

Comment: If the modulo is prime, it is Fermat's little theorem. And we have $\phi(n)=n-1$ in this case.

Comment: 19 is prime  isn't it?

Comment: Exactly that! :)